# Alter group element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 textarea with a default text "Write something". Let say if I click on one of them, the default text will disappear and that textarea get focus. However, if I click on another textarea, the default text of another textarea will disappear but the default text of first textarea will reappear. How can I make this happen? Same thing is that if I am to click on the third textarea, its default text of the textarea that I clicked on will disappear and the other will reappear.

Coding:

```
<textarea class="t" id="tt3">Write something</textarea>
<textarea class="t" id="tt3">Write something</textarea>
<textarea class="t" id="tt3">Write something</textarea>
```

How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Have you *written something* so far?

Comment: @Jason McCreary: I'd hope not. There are better ways to do this than home-rolling, and if you WERE home-rolling, I'd think you an incompetent developer.

Comment: @Stefan: I feel stupid asking, but what the heck is home-rolling?

Comment: @fehays - I assume he means to say *roll your own*, as in do it yourself or build it from scratch. I have no idea why that would make someone an incompetent developer. He's made absurd statements here before, and seems to be a [chronic downvoter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/78182/stefan-kendall). So don't take what he says too seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you declare a css with some classes:

```
.t {
    font-family: Helvetica, Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.txt-selected {
    font-style: normal;
}

.txt-unselected {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Then, in javascript you write:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var defaultText = "write something";

    $(".t")
        .addClass("txt-unselected")
        .val(defaultText)
        .focus(function () {

            var $this = $(this);

            if($this.val() == defaultText)
            {
                $this.val("");
                $this.removeClass("txt-unselected");
                $this.addClass("txt-selected");
            }
        })
        .blur(function () {

            var $this = $(this);

            if($this.val() == "")
            {                
                $this.removeClass("txt-selected");
                $this.addClass("txt-unselected");
                $this.val(defaultText);
            }
        });
});
```

That should do the work. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about (I think) is often referred to as a watermark.

Take a look at this:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Comment: How if it is not only apply on the default text, but it will change the style of textarea too when it got focus and blur? Thanks

Comment: jquery has focus and blur events.  take a look at the jquery.com documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the HTML5 [placeholder](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) attribute and falling back on a javascript solution if the browser doesn't support that attribute.

Comment: How if it is not only apply on the default text, but it will change the style of textarea too when it got focus and blur? Thanks.

Comment: The style? How do you mean? It will do the behavior you described in your original post.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for ya!

http://www.jsfiddle.net/86TTc/1/

I've tested this across a fairly wide-range of browsers (the same ones that jQuery supports).  I may have missed one or two, but this should get you 99.9% of the way there.

I hope this helps you both with your specific task, and helps you understand how it is done.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall, I guess I'm incompetent since I didn't use a plugin, eh?

Comment: -1 for lack of Modernizr and libraries to support this behavior. Your code is not re-usable or maintainable. This should obviously be handled by a library; the least you could have done would be write your code in plugin form, but even then it's shadier than just using an existing solution.

Comment: Loading a whole library for one line of code? No thanks. Your opinions have little bearing here. I've addressed the request *exactly* and you actively penalise me for it? And, you haven't even posted a solution yourself, just an idea. I think you've lost the plot.

Comment: I'll go further to that your behaviour here makes SO less than it could be.